# Unable to access web_accessible_resource when using extension_ids options in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I have an MV3 extension where I have a file which I want to access via content script.
I am unable to do that when I specify "extension_ids": ["myextId"] in manifest.json.
However when I use  "matches": ["<all_urls>"], I am able to access it.
According to chrome docs

> Each element must include a "resources" element and either a "matches"
> or "extension_ids" element.

I am getting the extension ID from extensions management page

[image]

Am i getting ID from the wrong place  ?

**Manifest.json**

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
   {
        "resources": [
            "/sample.html",
        ],
        "extension_ids": ["liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb"]
    }
]
```

Error

```
Denying load of <URL>. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
my.com/:40 Denying load of chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/sample.html. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.
```

Isnt the extension_Ids array supposed to contain the ids of all extensions that should be able to access it or am i understanding it wrong?

Comment: "Extension" in extension_ids means a context with a `chrome-extension://id/` URL and it's used to allow other extensions to access your resources, whereas content scripts run in the context of a web page which is `https://example.com/`. Hence you need to expose the resources everywhere your content scripts need them.